# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12 in android

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm getting the above error with my xml below. What is my issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/question"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="what is your name?"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

  <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/answer_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/question"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/radio_group_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

      <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/option1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="paru"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

      <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/option2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/option1"
        android:text="mani"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

      <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/option3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/option1"
        android:text="sankar"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

      <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/option4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/option2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@id/option2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/option3"
        android:text="venkat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    </RelativeLayout>
  </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my logcat shows:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
    at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5768)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove  `android:layout_marginLeft="@+id/option2"` from your `option4` `RadioButton`.As you cannot give any view as margin.And also make your alignment view ids as `@+id` and not `@id`

Try below data :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="what is your name?"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/answer_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/question"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/radio_group_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/option1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="paru"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/option2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/option1"
                android:text="mani"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/option3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/option1"
                android:text="sankar"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/option4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/option2"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/option3"
                android:text="venkat"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: its worked me fine thank u so much, after this i got a runtime exception like : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

form 

if (convertView == null) {
   view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.questions_lits_item,parent, true);
  } else {
   view = convertView;
  }

Comment: You saved me a lot of time. Thanx.